# Loop through files in a FTP using MS DOS

Tags: ftp, dos

Is there a way to loop through the files in an FTP from MS DOS.? Thanks.

Comment: By MS-DOS do you really mean good old 16 bit DOS?  That's  problematic because that OS doesn't even have TCP/IP on board as a standard, so any answer will be influenced by the choice of TCP/IP stack you're using.

Comment: @fvu : It is first generation of Windows TCP/IP stack on Windows XP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technique I'm using is to have two FTP scripts. One I use to capture the output of a DIR command. Having captured the DIR, I parse that for the names of files to be downloaded. Then I use the second script with information from the first to download the files.